# Parse JSON object in python Django framework

Tags: json

How to parse below JSON object in python to get part_number, product_name and quantity?

```
{'products': [{'part_number': 'sda', 'product_name': 'asdas', 'quantity': '12'}, {'part_number': 'asd', 'product_name': 'dfg', 'quantity': '3'}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'products': [{'part_number': 'sda', 'product_name': 'asdas', 'quantity': '12'}, {'part_number': 'asd', 'product_name': 'dfg', 'quantity': '3'}]}

for i in data['products']:
    print(i['product_name'])
```

same for other key values, since it is a `json object` you can directly use loop to get the values

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try importing json and parsing your object

```
   import json

    products=json.loads({'products': [{'part_number': 'sda', 'product_name': 'asdas', 'quantity': '12'}, {'part_number': 'asd', 'product_name': 'dfg', 'quantity': '3'}]})

    for product in products['products']:
      print product['part_number']
      print product['product_name']
      print product['quantity']
```